# MiniBlog: Getting 404 on admin functions after deploying as virtual app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, blogs, virtual-directory

I am using the below blog engine

https://github.com/madskristensen/MiniBlog

I have deployed the blog as a virtual dir in my existing mvc4 website and I am facing 404's on admin functions.

I cant login , create new post or update exiting post. The public pages works fine.

Like the below throws 404
mainsite.com/blog/post/new

the below works fine

www.mainsite.com/blog
www.mainsite.com/blog/post/my-existing-post

Wesbite: www.mainsite.com - main mv4 website
Blog: www.mainsite.com/blog - virtual app under my website which points to blog folder under root of my website. Blog folder contains the source and with the below web.config changes

[image]